# not having ecb-compile-*

Tags: emacs, elisp, text-editor, emacs-ecb

I've install cedet and ecb on my emacs and ecb seems right but sth is wrong here. the commands like ecb-compile-*** doesn't exist! and I need them to show compile section ( it isn't shown)

And the only think I have about compilation is ecb-toggle-compile-window which asks us about height of the window and after entering it, then it says it's too small and then ecb closes completely.

Any idea about it?

(CEDET 1.1 and ecb 2.32BETA3)

Comment: which versions of ECB/CEDET are you using?

Comment: CEDET 1.1 and ecb 2.32BETA3